# XML serialize which had xml-attribute by xml-element

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have to create a XML-document for an import in an other software. The import-process can not be modify, so the xml and his structure is fixed.

I work with VB.net in visualstudio. I use the "Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer" and is works fine for me in the past.

For this topics i normaly "rebuild" the whole xml-structure as classes with "xml modifier" like that:

```vb
Public Class Xyz
    <xmlattribute> property id as integer
    <xmlelement> property name as string
    <xmlelement> property comment as string
    <xmlelement> property block as string
    <xmlelement> property test as List(of Test)

    Public Sub New()
        test = new List(of Test)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Test
    <xmlelement> property name as string
End Class
```

and then I get xml-part like that:

```xml
<Xyz id=0>
 <Name>Abc</Name>
 <Comment>Abc</Comment>
 <Block>Abc</Block>
 <Test>
  <Name>Abc</Name>
 </Test>
 <Test>
  <Name>Def</Name>
 </Test>
 <Test>
  <Name>Ghi</Name>
 </Test>
</Xyz>
```

But now I have two problems in the xml, on which I need some inspiration from anybody. First, "Block" has a direct value (like before) and an attribute like the "id_block". And second, there is a serialnumber at the "Test" element. The import has to look like that:

```xml
<Xyz id=0>
 <Name>Abc</Name>
 <Comment>Abc</Comment>
 <Block id_Block=5>Abc</Block>
 <Test_0>
  <Name>Abc</Name>
 </Test_0>
 <Test_1>
  <Name>Def</Name>
 </Test_1>
 <Test_2>
  <Name>Ghi</Name>
 </Test_2>
</Xyz>
```

How can I implement these two topics?

Comment: You added an attribute to Block. Make Block a class with an XmlAttribute and XmlText

Comment: Also, you can serialize Test_1, Test_2, ... Test_n to an Object property with XmlAnyElement attribute. But then you have Objects...

Comment: Hey djv, your first comment works. Your second I do not understand. "Test" is a separate class. What I have to do with it, that i can modifiy the name?

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim xyz As Xyz = doc.Descendants("Xyz").Select(Function(x) New Xyz With { _
                                                        .id = CType(x.Attribute("id"), Integer), _
                                                        .name = CType(x.Element("Name"), String), _
                                                        .comment = CType(x.Element("Comment"), String), _
                                                        .block = CType(x.Element("Block"), String), _
                                                        .test = x.Elements().Where(Function(y) y.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Test")).Select(Function(y) CType(y.Element("Name"), String)).ToList()
                                                    }).FirstOrDefault()

    End Sub

End Module
Public Class Xyz
    Property id As Integer
    Property name As String
    Property comment As String
    Property block As String
    Property test As List(Of String)

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I do not want to change my tool-chain by switching to XDocument.

Comment: You would have to create a custom xml serialization class to handle the test_0, test_1, test_2, or have a hard coded class for each index number.

Comment: "Hard coded class for each index number" is really the last solution. Do you have an example for the custom-xml-serialization-class? Or other question, what is with "xmlarray" and "xmlarryitem" or "xmlanyelement? For me it is possible to have an additional variable in the class which provides the needed index number. But I do not know, how I use these number for the name.

Comment: To use arrays the names of the tags must be the same.  For custom serializer See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Did you see my solution. That i have to implement the interface in parent und child looks not so good. Any improvement suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My solution you see below. It works for me, but...

What I do not understand, why I need the IXMLSERIALIZER at the parent-class und at the (indexed)child-class. I tested otherwise, but it did not work. Everytime was e.g. the "test" tag inside and not only the "test_1" tag. Any good explanation for that or other/better solution?

My code:

```
  Public Class Xyz
        Inherits IndexedParent

        <XmlAttribute> Property id As Integer
        <XmlElement> Property name As String
        <XmlElement> Property comment As String
        <XmlElement> Property block As String
        <XmlIgnore> Property test As List(Of Test)
        <XmlIgnore> Property tryNext As List(Of TryNext)


        Public Sub New()
            test = New List(Of Test)
            tryNext = New List(Of TryNext)
            RegisterIndexedChildList(test)
            RegisterIndexedChildList(tryNext)
        End Sub

    End Class

    Public Class Test
        Inherits IndexedChild

        <XmlElement> Property Name As String
        <XmlElement> Property Name2 As String


    End Class


    Public Class TryNext
        Inherits IndexedChild

        <XmlElement> Property N As String
        <XmlElement> Property N2 As String

    End Class

    Public MustInherit Class IndexedParent
        Implements IXmlSerializable

        Private registeredChildLists As List(Of IEnumerable(Of IndexedChild))

        Public Sub RegisterIndexedChildList(pChildList As IEnumerable(Of IndexedChild))
            If registeredChildLists Is Nothing Then
                registeredChildLists = New List(Of IEnumerable(Of IndexedChild))
            End If
            registeredChildLists.Add(pChildList)
        End Sub


        Public Function GetSchema() As XmlSchema Implements IXmlSerializable.GetSchema
            Return Nothing
        End Function

        Public Sub ReadXml(reader As XmlReader) Implements IXmlSerializable.ReadXml
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Sub

        Public Sub WriteXml(writer As XmlWriter) Implements IXmlSerializable.WriteXml

            IndexedChild.WritePropertiesAsXml(writer, Me)

            For Each childList As IEnumerable(Of IndexedChild) In registeredChildLists
                IndexedChild.WriteAllXmlElements(writer, childList)
            Next

        End Sub

    End Class


    Public MustInherit Class IndexedChild
        Implements IXmlSerializable

        Public Shared Function WriteAllXmlElements(pWriter As XmlWriter, pList As IEnumerable(Of IndexedChild))
            For Each item As IXmlSerializable In pList
                pWriter.WriteStartElement(item.GetType.Name.ToString.ToLower + pList.ToList.IndexOf(item).ToString)
                item.WriteXml(pWriter)
                pWriter.WriteEndElement()
            Next
        End Function

        Public Shared Function WritePropertiesAsXml(pWriter As XmlWriter, pObj As Object)
            For Each prop As Reflection.PropertyInfo In pObj.GetType().GetProperties
                If Attribute.IsDefined(prop, GetType(XmlElementAttribute)) Then
                    pWriter.WriteElementString(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(pObj, Nothing))
                ElseIf Attribute.IsDefined(prop, GetType(XmlAttributeAttribute)) Then
                    pWriter.WriteAttributeString(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(pObj, Nothing))
                End If
            Next
        End Function

        Public Sub ReadXml(reader As XmlReader) Implements IXmlSerializable.ReadXml
            Throw New NotImplementedException
        End Sub

        Public Sub WriteXml(writer As XmlWriter) Implements IXmlSerializable.WriteXml
            WritePropertiesAsXml(writer, Me)
        End Sub

        Public Function GetSchema() As XmlSchema Implements IXmlSerializable.GetSchema
            Return Nothing
        End Function
    End Class
```